# Converting a html table into a json object and sending it to a php page ,the table has a input field

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have got a html table which is dynamically created by php code taking db data.
the table's last field is a input field for entering a number.
the data from the table has to be sent to another php page for sql insert.
i am new to xml and ajax pls help me out with the above javascript code.

```
<script>

$(document).ready("enter").click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var elementTable = document.getElementById("form_table");
    var jObject = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elementTable.rows.length; i++)
    {
        jObject[i] = [];
        jObject[i][0] = elementTable.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
        jObject[i][1] = elementTable.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;//data from input field
    }
    console.log(jObject);

    var JSONObject = encodeURIComponent(
        JSON.stringify(jObject));//GETTING ERROR HERE

    var url = "submit.php";
    var requestData = "&dtable=" + JSONObject;

    var XMLHttpRequestObj = FileResort.Utils.createRequest();
    XMLHttpRequestObj.open("POST", url, true);
    XMLHttpRequestObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    XMLHttpRequestObj.send(requestData);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing jquery (event) and non-jquery ajax call/dom querying ?

Answer (score 0):

as long as you are using JQuery, adapt [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/e7osd1e3/)

```
$("button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var tableArray = [];
    $("table tbody tr:has(td)").each(function(index,element){
        tableArray.push([
            $(this).find("td:eq(1)").html(),
            $(this).find("td:eq(2)").html()
            ]);
    });
    console.log(tableArray);
    $("div").text(encodeURIComponent(
        JSON.stringify(tableArray)
    ));
    return false;
});
```

which is mostly what you want for the table serialization minus the ajax call ( which I think should be a **POST**, but that is my personal opinion )